# How to get Form Body request using Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

in Postman the ***Body*** tab is suppose to be used for POST method. When I used ***Params*** tab to specify my request parameter and it got accepted.

[image]

how to accept only Form Body request instead of Parameters in POST method?

I used this package in my Request file
https://github.com/pearlkrishn/lumen-request-validate

Comment: Do you want to only **accept** POST content or only **retrieve** POST content ? By default Laravel/Lumen accept any extra URL/POST parameters. You will usually define what you want to retrieve to use them.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Post method for API, you should pass param in Body tab and use `dd($request->all())` to get params

Comment: Post method should not accept requests parameter came from Params Tab

Answer (score 0):

By default whether you use body or params to pass values to Laravel, you can get them through `request()->all()`.

Comment: I'm using Lumen and  request() method not exists in lumen.